# Host python bottle framework webpage

Tags: python, hosting, web-hosting, bottle

I'm developing an aplication built on the python Bottle framework. It's amazing and i want to host it somewhere, but of course i need a service where i can run the server.

What are the best options available (on costs too)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work for [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/), a Python hosting company, so obviously I think we have a great Bottle hosting solution -- check it out :-)

Some of our competitors -- ones where we feel proud if a customer leaves them to move to us, or where we don't feel too depressed if they leave us to go to them, are Webfaction, Heroku, and (if you don't mind doing OS maintenance yourself and setting up your own front-end webserver) Digital Ocean and Amazon Web Services.

There are definitely other good hosts, but those are the ones that spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check it out and maybe another customer.. ;)

Comment: Yay! :-)  I should also have mentioned that we have a free plan which is a great way to check it out (and even to run a low-traffic site if you don't need a custom domain name -- free apps run at `yourusername.pythonanywhere.com`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to host is use Ngrok ,its an open source tool where use get a temporary link where you can access your local host server on any machine  through that link .you can download it from here https://ngrok.com/